# Пунктуационные и синтаксические правки

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, причастия, причастный-оборот

Исходный текст:

> *Для живущих у нас на Сахалине корейцев это великий праздник...*

Текст, с моей правкой:

> *Для корейцев, живущих у нас на Сахалине, это — великий праздник...*

Верно ли я переделал предложение? а расставил знаки препинания? Как написать лучше?

Может ли причастный оборот стоять перед зависимым словом? Уточнение «на Сахалине» стоит обособлять запятыми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне больше нравится исходный вариант. Там всё верно. После перестановки оборота не так плавно, но кардинально ничего не меняется.

> Может ли причастный оборот стоять перед зависимым словом?

Да, но это не зависимое слово, а существительное. Здесь причастный оборот относится к зависимым элементам.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108 — пункт 2.

> Уточнение «на Сахалине» стоит обособлять запятыми?

Нет. Это разговорный вариант.

После "это" тире ставится при наличии паузы.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92 — пункт 7.